# "SCRIPT70: Permission denied" IE Edge trying to access the returnValue parameter of a child window

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, same-origin-policy, content-security-policy

I am receiving a "SCRIPT70: Permission denied" exception when trying to access the returnValue parameter of a child window I created. After some research, it appears that the issue has to do with IE's "same origin policy;" however, the parent and child windows are in the same domain, so I am a little stumped. I was under the impression that the below Content-Security-Policy header script-src value would solve the issue, but it remains. Any thoughts?

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// In web.config...

<system.webServer>
   ... 
   <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
         <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'none'; 
            script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.ourdomain.com www.google-analytics.com; 
            connect-src 'self' *.ourdomain.com; img-src 'self' www.google-analytics.com; 
            style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
      </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol> 
</system.webServer>


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// In PayorManager.aspx (e.g. https://www.ourdomain.com/Billing/PayorManager.aspx)

var url = "Payor.aspx?mode=Edit&payorID=392&sec=19";
var windowName = "PayorDetail";
var params = "width=980,height=775,left=150,top=124.5,alwaysRaised,scroll=0";

var childWindow = window.open(url, windowName, params);

// When the above childWindow closes, this gets executed...
 function _onChildCloseWrapper(childWindow, onChildClose) {
    if (onChildClose) {
       // THIS is where I get a "SCRIPT70: Permission denied" exception when trying to access
       // the returnValue parameter
       onChildClose(childWindow.returnValue);
    }

    return true;
};


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// In Payor.aspx (e.g. https://www.ourdomain.com/Billing/Payor.aspx),
// After postback and data saved

window.onload = function () {
   if (closeWindow == "1") {
      window.returnValue = "SAVED";
      self.close();
   }
};
```